# Javascript Unexpected Token { with conditionals

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put a JS conditional inside a listed order and have two radio buttons that I need to check and then proceed to the next list according to the selection.

```
<li data-input-trigger>
<label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">Welcome <br> <br> Is 
this application for yourself or someone else?</label>
<div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
    <span><input id="radio_myself" name="radMyself" type="radio" 
    value="choice"/>Myself</span>
    <span><input id="radio_else" name="radElse" type="radio" 
    value="choice"/>Someone Else</span>
<script>                                 
    if(document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked == true){
    //do this;
    }                                    
    else(document.getElementById("radio_else").checked == true){
    //do that;
    }
</script>
```

So if radio_myself is selected I want it display the next list which is

```
<li>
    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name?</label>
</li>
```

or the other list if the other radio button is selected.

I am not sure if I am implementing it right as I just started with JS and HTML. I keep getting the unexpected token error { in the else line of code.

Comment: you need `else if` here i think.

Comment: Let's start by closing the `<div>` and `<li>` tags. Then we can focus on the `if` and `else if` structure.

Comment: @RandyCasburn that is a part of the code. div and li has more to it .

Answer (score 2):

`else` does not accept a parameter. So you'll have to do another `if` inside the `else` if you want to check for that

```
if (document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked == true) {
  //do this;
} else {
  if (document.getElementById("radio_else").checked == true) {
    //do that;
  }
}
```

You can also check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), it's a really good resource if you want to look up how things work in JavaScript

Comment: No love for the `else if`? You don't have to nest the `if` block inside the `else`, merely writing `else if (condition)` on the same line would suffice.

Comment: It makes it easier for people new to JavaScript to understand. I think I'll leave it like that. (especially since there really isn't the construct of  `else if` in this language, just playing with single statements not needing the brackets and messing up the indentation)

Comment: Oh okay. It isn't giving me the error now but it looks like it isn't checking the conditionals. It just jumps to the next list. Also how can I add this in the if statement:

`<li>
    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name?</label>
</li>`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked == true){
    //do this;
}
else(document.getElementById("radio_else").checked == true){
    //do that;
}
```

**needs to be:**

```
if(document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked == true){
    //do this;
}
else if(document.getElementById("radio_else").checked == true){
    //do that;
}
```

**but you could rewrite as:** (assuming at least one radio must be checked)

```
if(document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked){
    //do this;
}
else {
    //do that;
}
```

`else` cannot contain a conditional. It will get executed only if the `if` and `else if`s above it are false.

Comment: Oh okay. It isn't giving me the error now but it looks like it isn't checking the conditionals. It just jumps to the next list. Also how can I add this in the if statement:

`<li><label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">What's your name?</label>
</li>

Comment: Do a little more studying up then come back to this problem. Promise, it'll be easy.